# Add comma separator to axis labels

Tags: r, plot, axis-labels

I have the following example where I am trying to add a comma seperator to numbers greater that 999(i.e. 1,000 2,000 3,000 ...)

```
#Dummy data
Data1 <- data.frame(flow = c(8000,8.5,6,7.1,9), SP_elev = c(20,11,5,25,50))
Data2 <- data.frame(flow = c(7000,7.2,6.5,8.2,8.5), SP_elev = c(13,15,18,25,19))
Data3 <- data.frame(flow = c(2000,3,5,7,9), SP_elev = c(20,25,28,30,35))
Data4 <- data.frame(flow = c(1000,4,6,8,9), SP_elev = c(13,15,18,25,19))
Data5 <- data.frame(flow = c(1000,4,6,8,9), SP_elev = c(13,15,18,25,19))
Data6 <- data.frame(flow = c(1000,4,6,8,9), SP_elev = c(22,23,25,27,29))

#Create Vector list (in place of list.files)
dataframes = list("Data1" = Data1, 
                  "Data2" = Data2, 
                  "Data3" = Data3,
          "Data4" = Data4,
          "Data5" = Data5,
          "Data6" = Data6)

# open the PDF device
pdf(file="Dummy_Example.pdf", paper="letter", height=10, width=8)

#Create array of plots 
par(mfrow=c(3,2))

#plot a with regression model
for (i in dataframes) {

plot (i[,c('flow', 'SP_elev')], xlab=expression(paste("Discharge (", ft^3, "/s)",sep = "")), ylab= "Elevation (m)", tck=0.02, adj = 0.5)
axis(side=1, at=axTicks(1), labels=formatC(axTicks(1), format="d", big.mark=','))

}

# close the PDF device
dev.off()
```

The x-axis labels are being plotted twice on the output PDF.  Where am i going wrong in the `axis` command in the above code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#Dummy data
Data1 <- data.frame(flow = c(8000,8.5,6,7.1,9), SP_elev = c(20,11,5,25,50))
Data2 <- data.frame(flow = c(7000,7.2,6.5,8.2,8.5), SP_elev = c(13,15,18,25,19))
Data3 <- data.frame(flow = c(2000,3,5,7,9), SP_elev = c(20,25,28,30,35))
Data4 <- data.frame(flow = c(1000,4,6,8,9), SP_elev = c(13,15,18,25,19))
Data5 <- data.frame(flow = c(1000,4,6,8,9), SP_elev = c(13,15,18,25,19))
Data6 <- data.frame(flow = c(1000,4,6,8,9), SP_elev = c(22,23,25,27,29))

#Create Vector list (in place of list.files)
dataframes = list("Data1" = Data1, 
                  "Data2" = Data2, 
                  "Data3" = Data3,
          "Data4" = Data4,
          "Data5" = Data5,
          "Data6" = Data6)

# open the PDF device
pdf(file="Dummy_Example.pdf", paper="letter", height=10, width=8)

#Create array of plots 
par(mfrow=c(3,2))

#plot a with regression model
for (i in dataframes) {

plot (i[,c('flow', 'SP_elev')], xlab=expression(paste("Discharge (", ft^3, "/s)",sep = "")), ylab= "Elevation (m)", tck=0.02, adj = 0.5, xaxt='n')
axis(side=1, at=axTicks(1), labels=formatC(axTicks(1),  big.mark=','))
}


# close the PDF device
dev.off()
```

To get the axis labels not not appear twice,  `xaxt='n'` needs to be added to the `plot` function.  The axis labels are formatted and  plotted when `axis` is called in the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Would the block starting with:

```
for (i in dataframes) {
```

Have any bearing on how many time `axis()` is being called?

I suggest moving the line:

```
axis(side=1, at=axTicks(1), labels=formatC(axTicks(1), format="d", big.mark=','))
```

Outside the for loop, like this:

```
for (i in dataframes) 
{
    plot (i[,c('flow', 'SP_elev')], xlab=expression(paste("Discharge (", ft^3, "/s)",sep = "")), ylab= "Elevation  m)", tck=0.02, adj = 0.5)
}
axis(side=1, at=axTicks(1), labels=formatC(axTicks(1), format="d", big.mark=','))
```

***Also, You can try*** calling argumnent axes=F in the additional calls to plot() to suppress the multiple plotting of the x-axis.

See the ***[link here](http://www.carlislerainey.com/2012/12/17/controlling-axes-of-r-plots/)*** for more on controlling axes.

Comment: Each time the loop executes, would that not result in calling axis() again, resulting in more than one axis being created?  How many times does the loop execute?

Comment: i tried the solution you posted above and it does not change the problem of having the numbers greater than a 999 from being plotted twice on the x axis.  If it is outside the loop, it will only effect the last plot (bottom left of the page).

Comment: Okay, sorry, I do not know what to suggest beyond that.

Comment: The loop is calling for a new plot every time it calls axis.  But  I see your point.

Comment: If the axis line is not in the for loop it will only effect the last plot (bottom left corner) of the array of plots on each page.

Comment: If using argument `axes=F`, then the first call to plot and `axis()` would be before the for loop, then the for loop would look similar to your original code, except for the argument added to `plot()` function.  I see you posted an answer though, so you must have it figured out!  Good.  (don't forget to mark your answer as answered)

Comment: apparently i cant makr it as answered for another two days.  I am still trying to get those rep points.